# C# - itextsharp - bad date format (DGV) and header

Tags: pdf, itext

I've a problem with itextsharp.

I generate a pdf from datagridview and dgv get data from an sql database. In one of the colums is a value date, but in the pdf it's formatted incorrectly. Example: `03-04-2014 00:00:00`, while in datagridview it's `03-04-2014` in database is as and in the database column for date (no smalldatetime). Why is the date formatted wrong in pdf?

Second question - How can I view the header and footer of the document? I'd use this to generate documents in two copies. The first copy of the header will be "original", second copy of the header will be "Copy".

Third question - How can I create a temporary files pdf, so that when you close the file it is removed from disk?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend asking one question at a time, rather than asking three in a single post.

Comment: First question, iTextSharp does not stringify date's, that's 100% .Net doing that so you'll need to check whatever code you're using to render it. Ignore iTextSharp for now and just save the HTML from your renderer and post that tagged ASP.Net and you might get some more specific help. Second question, no idea what you're asking. How are you "viewing" it? In Adobe Reader, programmatically? Third, see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/546049/231316

Comment: Ok Thanks! Now I saving to html and it's better than iTextSharp